# How to get file sizes of large files in OS X Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, file

I'm trying to get the file size of a big file (1GB +) using the OS X Terminal. I'm using `du -sh`. But also after 30 seconds I don't have any result, is there any faster command?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get the size of a single file or all files in a given location?

Comment: It's different, sometimes it is a folder, file or application.

Comment: You don't need the `-s` option for a single file. `du -h <file>` will do the job.

Comment: Try `ls -lh filename`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you are looking for big files in your home directory, use this command:

```
find ~ -size +1G
```

Replace **~** with the directory of interest.

## Update

My original response was wrong, but I'll keep it to remind myself. If you are trying to get the size of a file, try this:

```
stat -f '%z' filename  # Normal file
stat -L -f '%z' filename  # symbolic link file
```

I have not figure out how to do it for a directory yet.

Comment: The `z` option list the total number of bytes used in the file but not the total blocks allocated to the file. To get the total allocated size of a file in bytes you could do something like `echo "$(( $(stat -f'%b' filename) * 512 ))"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command

> $ sudo find / -type f -size +1G

In case you want to avoid traversing mounted drives, your command should be:

> $ sudo find -x / -type f -size +1G